# SQL multiple columns in single WHERE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to implement a query with multiple columns in a single where condition. But it making an sql error.
My original query is like this

```
SELECT id 
FROM usertable 
WHERE (user_addedon BETWEEN '2013-07-02 00:00:01' AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
   OR (user_deletedon BETWEEN '2013-07-02 00:00:01' AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
   OR (user_modified BETWEEN '2013-07-02 00:00:01' AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
```

What i am trying to do is to avoid the repetition of the `BETWEEN`. From another SO post [SQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause) i created a query query like this

```
SELECT id 
FROM usertable 
WHERE (user_addedon,user_deletedon,user_modifiedon) BETWEEN '2013-07-02 00:00:01' AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59'
```

But it is showing an error `ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented`.
Is it because it cannot be implemented on PostgreSQL or is there any mistake in the query.
 Also like to know if there are any other method to implement this?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the other post shows you how to do an `IN` query with multiple columns, this does not indicate that it is possible with other operators such as `BETWEEN`.

As far as I know, the only way to achieve what you want it the way you show at the beginning of your question, with 3 `BETWEEN` statements :( Sucks I know but that's SQL

Answer (score 1):

In case someone lands here looking for a solution that works in 9.2+, the date range type does it. This query returns `true`

```
select
    daterange'[2013-07-02, 2013-08-02)'
    @> any (array['2013-07-01', '2013-07-15', '2013-08-02']::date[])
```

The `@>` operator means "range contains element". The `any` operator works very much like `in`. The `[` in the range means an inclusive bound while the `)` means exclusive.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18030

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just as an exercise as I think the list of `between` is clearer

```
select id 
from usertable 
where exists (
    select 1
    from
        (values (user_addedon, user_deletedon, user_modified)) ud(ud)
        cross join
        (values ('2013-07-02'::date, '2013-08-02'::date)) r(ri, re)
    where ud >= ri and ud < re
)
```