# Parameterized IN clause using multiple columns

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I have a query along these lines, where I am trying to filter the result set by comparing tuples (like *[SQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause)*):

```
select *
from mytable
where (key, value) in (values
 ('key1', 'value1'),
 ('key2', 'value2'),
 ...
);
```

This is valid syntax and works fine on my PostgreSQL 9.3 database.

I want to invoke this query through Spring JDBC where the `in` value pairs come from a `List<Map<String, String>>`.

It would be nice to do something like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> valuesMap = ...;
String sql = "select * from mytable where (key, value) in (values :valuesMap)";
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("valuesMap", valuesMap);
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, rowMapper);
```

When I try this, I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setMap(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1707) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1910) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gStatement.setObject(AbstractJdbc3gStatement.java:36) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc4Statement.java:47) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:427) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:150) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:287) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:244) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:623) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

I've looked at the the hstore extension it mentions.  It doesn't seem relevant to my problem.

Is there a way to accomplish this without dynamically building the SQL and parameter list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you have to do is to pass a list of arrays, where each array contains a key and value, like this:

```
HashMap<String , String > map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key0", "value0");
map.put("key1", "value1");
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
List<String[]> valuesMap = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key:keys){
    String[] entry = {key,map.get(key)};
    valuesMap.add(entry);
}
String sql = "select * from mytable where (key, value) in (values :valuesMap)";
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("valuesMap", valuesMap);
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, rowMapper);
```

This is mentioned in the Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  In hindsight, Object[] makes more sense than a Map anyway.

Comment: Just to be clear, in the code sample the final list will contain two arrays: 
[key1, value1]
[key0, value0]

Comment: If like me you were here to do the same thing in jpa, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190664/jpa-criteria-in-clause-with-many-columns

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't any easy way to bind a nested collection bind variable to PostgreSQL. You could generate the following SQL string instead

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (key, value) IN (
  (?, ?),
  (?, ?),
  ...
);
```

That's a bit of work to keep the SQL string and the variable bindings in sync.
You could, however, encode the map as JSON as such:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (key, value) IN (
  SELECT 
    t->>'key', 
    t->>'value'
  FROM json_array_elements(?) AS t(v)
)
```

E.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (key, value) IN (
  SELECT 
    t->>'key', 
    t->>'value'
  FROM json_array_elements(
    '[{"key":"key1","value":"value1"}, 
      {"key":"key2","value":"value2"}]'
  ) AS t(v)
)
```

In that case, you would only ever need a single `VARCHAR` bind variable

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get your solution to work, you could also just concatenate the key and value.
Perhaps JDBC has less problems with this more basic syntax:

```
select *
from mytable
where (key||value) in (
 ('key1value1'),
 ('key2value2'),
 ...
);
```

For this to work, you'd need to first convert your Java Map to a List with the key and values concatenated as well.

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea to use a separator between key and value, which doesn't appear in the data. E.g. `key || '###' || value` (until it *does* appear in the data, of course)

Answer (score -1):

It might not be an issue with the query, it might be that you don't have any hstore created/installed.

I suggest the following steps to debug your problem:

1. Try a very simple query, without any parameters.
2. If you get the same issue, check how to create extensions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html
3. Otherwise, if the query executed correctly, try to use a simple parameter (with `=?`)
4. Finally, try named queries. Something like:

```
ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(namedSql);
List<Integer> parameters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (A a : paramBeans)
    parameters.add(a.getId());
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("placeholder1, parameters);
// create SQL with ?'s
String sql = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, parameterSource);
return sql;
```

Also check this discussion, I find it useful: [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)