# JPA Criteria : in clause with many columns

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, in-clause

I am trying to write the following SQL query using the JPA Criteria API

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a
WHERE (a.category, a.priority) IN (
SELECT a1.category, max(a1.priority) FROM Table1 a1 GROUP BY a1.category
)
```

Functionally, the query select the element of Table1 with the highest priority for each category.

```
categoryPriority = // defines the pair category/priority
mySubQuery = // defines the subquery
query.where(categoryPriority.in(mySubQuery)
```

This is schematically what I am looking for.

Defining the subquery is not a problem since it is well documented.

But I cannot find a way to define the couple (a.category, a.priority).

Answer (score 6):

Multiple columns in a `IN` clause is not provided for in JPA. I think you would need to use a native query.

Reference: [query for select which multiple values in the “IN” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660081/query-for-select-which-multiple-values-in-the-in-clause)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Since I don't want to use native queries I replaced the many column part by an ugly concatenation of the value of the category and priority columns but I'm kind of disappointed.

Comment: please submit a request for JPA spec.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use field concatenation

Create a method that returns the two fields you want to search in your DTO/Entity.

```
  public String getField1Field2Concatenated() {
    return field1+ field2;
  }


List<String> ids = list.stream().map(r -> r.getField1Field2Concatenated()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can concatenate two fields and do the search.

```
Select e from Entity e where concat(e.field1,  c.field2) in (:ids)
```

If any of the fields are not text you can cast

```
Select e from Entity e where concat(cast(c.field1 as string),  c.field2) in (:ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like I answered in the [Discourse question](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/deprecation-of-hibernate-criteria-and-how-we-can-still-prevent-it/788/39) that was referring to this Stackoverflow post, the Hibernate extension of the JPA `CriteriaBuilder` is `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` which offers you a more or less stable API. I might be wrong with this, but I believe that tuple comparisons are not deemed stable enough yet, which is why this feature is only defined on `NodeBuilder`, which is defined in terms of the incubating SQM APIs.
You can use `NodeBuilder.tuple(null, root.get("attr1"), root.get("attr2")).in(subquery)` to model the same thing in terms of JPA Criteria API.