# Multiple columns for the same WHERE IN set

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose I want to find out all the people who are either parent or child of an specific set of people.

I could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM people P
WHERE
  P.parent_id IN ('111', 'abc', '42', '1a2b3c') OR
  P.child_id IN  ('111', 'abc', '42', '1a2b3c')
```

Is there any way in which I could avoid writing the list twice (or more times if I were looking for more columns)?

I'm looking for  something like:

`(...) WHERE (P.parent_id OR P.child_id) IN ('111', 'abc', '42', '1a2b3c')`

I'm using Oracle, but a plain SQL solution would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH search_ids (id) AS (
          SELECT '111'    FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'    FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '42'     FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '1a2b3c' FROM dual
) 
SELECT * FROM people P 
WHERE P.parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM search_ids)
  OR  P.child_id IN (SELECT id FROM search_ids)
;
```

The `FROM dual` bit is Oracle specific.

Happy playing

Marco

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this technique, but creating an actual table. In my case, the set of the `WHERE IN` was very long and I wanted to discard that some problems I had were due to the length of this string making the query text too long for our connector. This approach reduced the query length and actually worked.

Comment: It is not the best approach to still use `OR` for this. In case you query was a bit more complex, its performance could reduce dramatically. See my answer for another approach doing the same using SET operator `intersect`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance and universality, it's better to use the other approach than `OR` for such a case. In Oracle, there are **SET** operators which could help you very much. For example for your case, your query could look like this:

```
select *
from people p
where
    exists (
        (
            select p.parent_id from dual
            union all
            select p.child_id from dual
        ) intersect (
            select '111' from dual
            union all
            select 'abc' from dual
            union all
            select '42' from dual
            union all
            select '1a2b3c' from dual
        )
    )
```

Or using `with` clause:

```
with people_list (value) as  (
            select '111' from dual
            union all
            select 'abc' from dual
            union all
            select '42' from dual
            union all
            select '1a2b3c' from dual
) 
select * from people p
where
    exists (
        (
            select p.parent_id from dual
            union all
            select p.child_id from dual
        ) intersect (
            select value from people_list
        )
    )
```

**Benefits of such an approach:**

1. It is better in terms of performance (as it was already mentioned, it is hard for optimizer to digest `OR`s in queries, especially when they are a bit more complex).
2. It is more universal - indeed, you can add as many columns as you want to be checked if they are in the given set of values.
3. Instead of selecting from `dual`, you can use any existing table in your schema.
4. This subquery integrates much easier into a complex query (and more efficiently as I already mentioned in the first point).

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `OR`, so the query is hard to optimize.  Hence, regular expressions are an option:

```
SELECT *
FROM people P
WHERE regexp_like('[' || P.parent_id || ']['  || p.child_id || ']') regexp_like('\[111|abc|42|1a2b3c\]')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a hierarchical query (and then it's more general - you can use different cutoffs by `LEVEL`):

```
select *
from   people
connect by level <= 2
       and parent_id = prior child_id
start with child_id in ( ..... )
```

It would still be best to have the "search id's" in a separate table, and the IN condition as `in (select search_id from helper_table)` as shown in another answer.

Comment: I like the idea behind this, anyway this query won't work as expected. It only selects those rows for which the child_id column is in the set of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #People(parent_id NVARCHAR(50),child_id NVARCHAR(50))
GO
INSERT INTO #People
    ( parent_id, child_id )
VALUES  ( N'111', -- parent_id - nvarchar(50)
      N'321331'  -- child_id - nvarchar(50)
      ),( N'111', -- parent_id - nvarchar(50)
      N'abc'  -- child_id - nvarchar(50)
      ),( N'42', -- parent_id - nvarchar(50)
      N'321331'  -- child_id - nvarchar(50)
      ),( N'111', -- parent_id - nvarchar(50)
      N'1a2b3c'  -- child_id - nvarchar(50)
      ),( N'11dsdfs1', -- parent_id - nvarchar(50)
      N'1a2sdfsdfsb3c'  -- child_id - nvarchar(50)
      )
;WITH CTE (Value) AS (
      SELECT '111'    
     UNION SELECT 'abc'   
     UNION SELECT '42'    
     UNION SELECT '1a2b3c' 
  ) 
SELECT *
FROM #People p
WHERE EXISTS(
    (SELECT p.parent_id 
    UNION 
    SELECT p.child_id
    )
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT value
    FROM CTE
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably group them using something like below [Brevity: idea taken from [SQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause])

```
WHERE (P.parent_id, P.child_id)  IN (('111','111'), ('abc','abc'),('42','42'), ('1a2b3c','1a2b3c'));
```

Comment: This is not exacly what I need. For instance if for a given person `P.parent_id` *is* in the list, but `P.child_id` *is not*, that person will not be selected, despite I do want to select it.

Comment: This query solves a different task and it is better to be rewritten with `AND` operator.