# More elegant syntax for DELETE WHERE on list of two columns pair

Tags: sql

I have 100 rows that I need deleted, based on a `PersonId` and `CarModel`. Some `PersonId` could have multiple `CarModel`s, so if I use

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE PersonId IN (
    101,
    102,
    103,
    104
)
AND CarModel IN (
    'Honda Accord',
    'Ford Explorer',
    'Other car model',
    'Last car model'
)
```

Then that will have false positives of delete 101, 'Ford Explorer' which I don't want. only 101, 'Honda Accord' and 102, 'Ford Explorer'

I could format it as

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE 
(PersonId = 101 AND CarModel = 'Honda) Accord' 
OR (PersonId = 102 AND CarModel = 'Ford Explorer')
OR (PersonId = 103 AND CarModel = 'model 1')
OR ( PersonId = 104 AND CarModel = 'model 2')
```

But that's kinda ugly. Is there cleaner syntax? I can't find a multi-column where clause for big lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of SQL (MySQL, Oracle) support multiple columns in an `IN` expression:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE (PersonId, CarModel) IN ((101, 'Honda Accord'), (102, 'Ford Explorer'), (103, 'model 1'), ...)
```