# Using single SELECT instead of multiple select in a loop for matching rows

Tags: sql, oracle, kotlin

I have a Oracle table with userId and adId (and some other stuff like ad Description, Date Posted etc.). I want to determine if matching userId, adId row exists or not like `SELECT * from Ad WHERE userId=xxx and adId=yyy` for a list of `userId` and `adId` object, e.g. `listOf<UserAd>()` (using kotlin)

Can I do this in one SELECT statement, instead of looping over UserAd pair in the list and collecting data for which pair the row exists and for which pair it does not? I need to find out for which pair, row exists and for which pair row does not exist.

Comment: Could you create a temp table with those values and simply outer join the two or use intersect/minus operators?  If both are in tables this is a simple full outer join and not a where statement at all...  `SELECT * FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B on A.userID = B.UserID and A.ADID = B.ADID` when neither side is null you have a match, where one side is null you don't...  Having the data from your listof() in a table gives you a great amount of flexablity

Comment: You could also use an "In" with multiple columns `SELECT city FROM user WHERE (firstName, lastName) IN (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'));` and "Build" your in via parameters  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027708/sql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause  but I think generating a temp table then doing the work is likely the easiest/most efficient.

Comment: @xQbert, creating temp tables, inserting data into the temp tables and doing a joint vs. looping over the list data making select call multiple time. Which is better for performance?

Comment: Every language should have some flavor of prepared statement and batch execution. Use this combination, which should (by implementation) do this without extra roundtrips compared to row-by-row execution. Looks like Kotlin uses the same as Java: [`preparedStatement.addBatch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/sql/PreparedStatement#addbatch) and `preparedStatement.executeQuery`.